# How can I find the index of the cell from map coordinates?

Tags: ros, navigation, position, costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I have the (x,y,z) position of the map. From that information, how can I find the cell index and also costmap value(free, obstacle ...) related to this coordinates ?

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285058/how-can-i-find-the-index-of-the-cell-from-map-coordinates-?/) by [Developer](https://answers.ros.org/users/31478/developer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 69 on 2018-03-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[worldToMap](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/kinetic-devel/costmap_2d/include/costmap_2d/costmap_2d.h#L143)

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2018-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Developer](https://answers.ros.org/users/31478/developer/) on 2018-03-12**:
Hi David, I could not understand your solution proposal. Let me explain the case better. I have a position(x,y,z) of a map on Rviz. And from that position information, I want to first find related cell index(I m no sure, if gridcell or costmap).Than I want to change this cost value manually.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2018-03-13**:
Do you have a `Costmap2dROS` object that you are manipulating in code?

**Comment by [Developer](https://answers.ros.org/users/31478/developer/) on 2018-03-14**:
No I don t have.
I try to get the position of the related grid from the position of the interactive marker that I put on the Rviz (map). And change the value of this grid.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

David is right , in detail , you can see the code in [worldToMap](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/kinetic-devel/costmap_2d/include/costmap_2d/costmap_2d.h#L143) below:

```
  /**
   * @brief  Given two map coordinates... compute the associated index
   * @param mx The x coordinate
   * @param my The y coordinate
   * @return The associated index
   */
  inline unsigned int getIndex(unsigned int mx, unsigned int my) const
  {
    return my * size_x_ + mx;
  }
```

---

Originally posted by [lsw](https://answers.ros.org/users/33525/lsw/) with karma: 46 on 2018-03-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Developer](https://answers.ros.org/users/31478/developer/) on 2018-03-14**:
thanks man !

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2018-03-14**:
This only works if the unsigned ints are already in map coordinates. You first have to run worldToMap or [the equivalent math operations](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/kinetic-devel/costmap_2d/src/costmap_2d.cpp#L208)